# Multiple echos of the same variable

Tags: php, html

So I have a variable, its called $comments.

but every time I do it I want it to break a line and echo out the new one I submit. Right now it just replaces the current one.

So everytime I click submit I would like it to make a NEW comments and not just write over the old one.

this is what I currently have, But everytime i hit submit it just overwrites the previous comment. I want it to break a line and display the next one without erasing teh previous

```
<?php
                session_start();

                if(isset($_POST['add'])){
                $text = $_POST['content'];
                $author = $_POST['author'];
                $comment = $text. ',' .$author;
                $_SESSION['cm'] = $comment;
                echo '<b>';
                }

                ?>

                <!DOCTYPE>
                <html>
                <head>
                    <style>
                        body{
                            text-align: center;
                            margin: 10px 0 0 0;
                        }
                        .listing{
                            text-align: left;
                            border-top: 2px solid #000;
                            padding: 15px;
                        }
                        input{
                            font-size: 16px;
                            padding: 5px;
                            text-align: center;
                        }
                        input[type=submit]{
                            display: block;
                            margin: auto;
                            margin-top: 10px;
                        }
                        #gotolink{
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 15px;
                            right: 15px;
                        }
                        .listing > div{
                            max-width: 100%;
                            word-break: break-all;
                        }




                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div id="gotolink"><button onClick='document.getElementById("bottom").scrollIntoView({block: "end", behavior: "smooth"});'>Scroll to bottom</button></div>
                    <p>Try and stay</p>
                        <p>Creating new test</p>
                            <form action="" method="POST">
                            <input type="text" name="content" placeholder="Text">
                            <input type="text" name="author" placeholder="Name">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="add">
                        </form>
                        <div class="listing">
                            <?php echo '<div>' .$_SESSION['cm']. '</div>';  ?>
                        </div>
                    <div id="bottom"></div>
                </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: you want to display all comments??

Comment: You will need to persist the data in some way, ie. `$_SESSION`, store to a database, hidden input, etc. The method would depend on how long to you want to save/append the data.

Comment: I ant the data to create a new <div> and just be displayed in the html without saving to any type of Db.

Comment: You can do this all on the client side, you don't need a server.

Comment: Your code does not match `<input type="text" name="comments"` vs `$text = $_POST['content'];`. Also, you are assigning the values to a session var, but overwritting it each time, and never echoing it.

Comment: Use String concontination operator for this like ` $_SESSION['cm']  .= $comment;`

Comment: I dont really get what your saying, I updated my code. All I want to do is be able to echo out the comments and each time they create a new line and do NOT replace the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $_SESSION['cm'] = $comment;
```

Replace with:

```
$_SESSION['cm'] .= $comment."<br>";
```

Comment: wtf I did that earlier and it didnt work.. why would it work now. So weird, thanks though. Worked perfectly.